# origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

Access to font at 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/FuturaBT-Light.woff' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'example.com'.

getting this error in my wordpress Bitnami instance AWS How fix this

I am using wp-cors as plug in

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`. Unify these addresses so they're both `https://www.example.com` or `https://example.com` to avoid CORS policy errors.